# Android - One button changing to next screen created. How to do next one?

Tags: java, android, xml

I created very simple button directing to new screen from this tutorial:
www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen
and it works fine.

The question is how to make a button returning from main2.xml to main.xml (and every next one button). I am not very good at it yet and logically i tried to create button with @id:button2 and a class App3Activity.java the same as App2Activity.java but changed button1 to button2 and main to main2. However, it crashed. What is wrong ?

Crash log: http://pastebin.com/bmcVMmJ0

Code: http://pastebin.com/8p6GwG3u

Comment: Do not provide code and ask what is wrong - is wrong. Please provide crash log and some code.

Comment: Crash log and code attached to main post

Answer (score 0):

there are many reason regarding your scenario

- Activity not defined in Manifest file
- Calling button in activity may not getting its view to trigger its functionality
- using 2 different XML in same Activity
- Intent not instantiated properly
- Context Switching is not proper
  there are many reasons behind your its an open ended Question unless you provide stacktace (Logcat) or code that you are working with

Comment: you have not defined your AppActivity3 in manifest 
so the thing is when you go from ativity 1 -3 DVM daangles out and could not found the resource you are pointing to that is causing app crash define activity 3 in manifest file and then run it will work perfectly

Comment: OK, it won't crash anymore but button on main2 is still unclickable

Comment: in main 2 you have not defined your button and also not defied it as click able  so make its refrence from XML main2 and then call button`s function onClickListener

Comment: It's the same code of button as in main.xml, defined as button1

Answer (score 0):

**App3Activity** is not declared in manifest file.

**AppActivity** is starting **App2Activity**, but **App2Activity** doesn't initialize button and click listener.

Comment: It's not crashing, that's fine after adding to manifest. So editing properly App2Activity would solve the problem?